# TTFB vs SEO and My Site Location

Tags: seo, performance

I have a website and about 90% of the users are Brazilian, so I migrated my website to be hosted on a America/São Paulo server on Google Cloud Platform.

However, after the migration I noticed that most sites that test performance for SEO show a TTFB of around 500~700ms, but for users from Brazil the TTFB is only 50ms.

Technically, speed is great for my users, but my fear is that SEO will be affected by this.
Should I worry about this and move the server to the US?

From Web.dev it says that TTFB is not a vital metric, and my site currently has good grades*.

- According to PageSpeed ​​Insight, I don't know if it measures in real time or through user history.

Comment: I expect Google will be looking at it from its nearest DC, so TTFB should not make much difference - if your users are local.   I do wonder though why there is such a difference in TTFB - are you loading a lot of small resources taking latency?     Another important thing to consider - Google really only cares about mobile performance (ie artificially constrained CPU and bandwidth).  Are you sure you are not confusing mobile TTFS to Desktop TTFB?  (Lighthouse produces different results for mobile and desktop)

Answer (score 1):

Google measures and cares about real user experience using their Core Web Vitals, which includes their metrics for speed called Largest Contentful Paint (LCP). TTFP can be a big contributor to LCP as nothing can happen until TTFB.

As the data they use comes from real user experiences, you should see good scores.

Check them out in your Google Search Console for the site under the Core Web Vitals tab on the right.

And it would be nice to know how you are doing to help confirm to others this is the case.